# How to display an image when a button is pressed in JavaFX

Tags: image, button, javafx, imageview, eventhandler

I'm having trouble figuring out how to display an image when a button is pressed. Here's what I have so far:

---

public class Flags extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
   //Create a label to display a prompt
    Label promptLabel = new Label("Select Button to Display a Flag");

   //Create buttons to display the flags
    Button americanButton = new Button("American Flag");
    Button canadianButton = new Button("Canadian Flag");
    Button frenchButton = new Button("French Flag");
    Button germanButton = new Button("German Flag");
    Button mexicanButton = new Button("Mexican Flag");


    //Creating an HBox
    HBox hbox = new HBox(10, promptLabel);
    HBox hbox1 = new HBox(10, americanButton);
    HBox hbox2 = new HBox(10, canadianButton);
    HBox hbox3 = new HBox(10, frenchButton);
    HBox hbox4 = new HBox(10, germanButton);
    HBox hbox5 = new HBox(10, mexicanButton);

    americanButton.setOnAction(new AmericanButtonHandler());


    //Creating a VBox
    VBox vbox = new VBox(10, hbox, hbox1, hbox2, hbox3, hbox4, hbox5);

    //set vbox padding
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    //set vbox alignment
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    //gridpane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox4.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox5.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    //Create a scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Flags");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

class AmericanButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        Pane aPane = new HBox(10);

        //Create new image
        Image americanImage = new Image("file:America.png");

        //Create new imageView
        ImageView aImageView = new ImageView(americanImage);

        aImageView.setImage(americanImage);
    }
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

---

So what I want to happen, is when the americanButton is pressed, the event handler is invoked allowing for the image to display. I've gotten to this point and can't seem to get passed it. Someone help!

Comment: Please actually post your relevant code as text instead of as an external image.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code%20as%20an%20image%20because%3A&text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,for%20us%20to%20do%20so.). Instead, paste you code and [format it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: You need a reference to the layout you want to add the `ImageView` to. With your current setup that can be accomplished by adding a constructor to your `AmericanButtonHandler` with the necessary parameter and storing the argument in an instance field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like the bottom function(Note:I modified some code to my liking it won't affect anything on your end its just how I prefer to look at it) I see you are not creating a scene stage or showing the stage if you look at the bottom function that should give you a good idea of what you should be doing the only thing I pass is a file path so it should be fairly easy to implement and understand

```
public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //Create a label to display a prompt
        Label promptLabel = new Label("Select Button to Display a Flag");

        //Create buttons to display the flags
        Button americanButton = new Button("American Flag");
        americanButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            showFlagAction(getClass().getResource("/TestImage.png").toExternalForm());
        });

        Button canadianButton = new Button("Canadian Flag");
        Button frenchButton = new Button("French Flag");
        Button germanButton = new Button("German Flag");
        Button mexicanButton = new Button("Mexican Flag");


        //Creating an HBox
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10, promptLabel);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        HBox hbox1 = new HBox(10, americanButton);
        hbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox hbox2 = new HBox(10, canadianButton);
        hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox hbox3 = new HBox(10, frenchButton);
        hbox3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox hbox4 = new HBox(10, germanButton);
        hbox4.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox hbox5 = new HBox(10, mexicanButton);
        hbox5.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        //Creating a VBox
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10, hbox, hbox1, hbox2, hbox3, hbox4, hbox5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Flags");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showFlagAction(String filePath){
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(filePath));

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.getChildren().add(imageView);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```